# Realizar una figura con CSS

Tags: css

Como puedo relizar la forma de color verde en la foto en css. Es para hacer el juego simon dice.Gracias!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podria usar border-top-left-radius para redondear el borde izquierdo, pero como hago para lograr la forma redondeada del lado inferior derecho?

Comment: CSS no esta diseñado para crear figuras, se puede, pero seria... muy forzado, para dibujo vectorial usa svg.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes realizar es, en vez de ponerle color al `div`, asignarle un borde del mismo tamaño que el `div` que hayas creado y asignarle un color a este. De esta forma, te quedará el borde superior redondeado a la vez que el inferior.

Tienes que tener en cuenta que le tendrás que asignar el borde dependiendo de la sección del círculo a la que estés haciendo referencia. Por ejemplo, en este caso se la tendrías que asignar arriba y a la izquierda (`border-top` y `border-left` respectivamente).

Ejemplo:

```css
#curvo{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 100px green solid;
  border-left: 100px green solid;
  border-top-left-radius:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="curvo"></div>
```

Comment: Me gusta tu solución muy ingeniosa :-)

Comment: Me acorde de este proyecto:
https://pattle.github.io/simpsons-in-css/